# $r$ cards dealt from well-shuffled deck

Tags: probability

> Example
>
> Let us see how may $5$-card poker hands there are. A hand consists of five cards drawn from a standard deck of $52$ cards. The order is unimportant, so a hand is just a combination of five cards drawn from $52$. Therefore there are ${52 \choose 5}=2598960$ possible hands, and each has probability $1/2598960$

Now, suppose a deck of $52$ cards is placed in a random order in which all $52! $permutations have the same probability. Show that if $r$ cards are dealt, then all ${52 \choose r}$ combinations have the same probability.

Can someone give me a hint? This seems so obvious that I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

We can group all $52!$ permutations of cards, such that the first $r$ cards of each group are identical. Every group will have the same amount of members, $\frac{52!}{\binom{52}r}$, so that the probability of choosing a permutation from any two sets will be the same. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove instead that in r cards there is a situation where we DON'T have the same probability.

Force a contradiction by showing this situation occurs when our 52 cards has a duplicate, hence our contradiction. (52 distinct cards)

Hope I didn't give too much away.